# How do you display a sprite location in real time during drag and drop (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, dynamic-text

I'm trying to figure out how I can show an object's X/Y coordinates while it's being dragged across the stage.

If I have a square located at 0,0 and I drag it to a new location--for example 50,50--I want to show the square's location **as** it is being dragged, not just when it's dropped. So the coordinate numbers will be constantly changing as the object is dragged.

Right now my code only detects the object's X/Y location when dragging starts and when dragging stops:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startDragging, true);
this.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopDragging, true);

function startDragging(e:MouseEvent) {

square1.startDrag();
xDisplay_txt.text = square1.x;
yDisplay_txt.text = square1.y;

}

function stopDragging(e:MouseEvent) {

testStage1.stopDrag();
xDisplay_txt.text = testStage1.x;
yDisplay_txt.text = testStage1.y;

}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call a certain handler, while you are dragging that thing, on a regular basis in order to update the output texts. The simplest way is to use the **ENTER_FRAME** event that fires, as its name states, every frame.

```
import flash.display.Sprite;

import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

// We may drag different objects, we need to know which one.
var currentDrag:Sprite;

// A list of objects we can drag.
var aList:Array = [square1, square2];

// Iterate over all the items in the list
// and subscribe to each one separately.
for each (anItem:Sprite in aList)
{
    anItem.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onStart);
}

function onStart(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // Store, which one object is being dragged.
    // Read on difference between Event.target and Event.currentTarget.
    currentDrag = e.currentTarget as Sprite;
    currentDrag.startDrag();

    // Subscribe to ENTER_FRAME event to control the way of things.
    // We need to do it only if we drag square1, as requested.
    if (currentDrag == square1)
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);
    }

    // Subscribe to stage, because this way you will handle the
    // MOUSE_UP event even if you release the mouse somewhere outside.
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStop);
}

function onFrame(e:Event):void
{
    // This event fires every frame, basically, every 40 ms.
    // Round the coordinates and update the texts.
    xDisplay_txt.text = int(currentDrag.x).toString();
    yDisplay_txt.text = int(currentDrag.y).toString();
}

function onStop(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    // That is also why we are keeping the refference
    // to the object we are dragging: to know which one to drop.
    currentDrag.stopDrag();

    // We're not dragging anything anymore.
    currentDrag = null;

    // Unsubscribe, as it is no longer needed.
    // That's fine even if we didn't subscribed to in in the first place.
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onFrame);

    // Unsubscribe from this one too.
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, onStop);
}
```

Comment: Organis - Thanks!! This works perfectly. Will this be effected by (or have an effect on) other draggable objects on the stage?

Comment: @dzinermachine The code above tracks exactly one object accessible by instance name **square1**. Do you have a list of similar objects you want to drag and track?

Comment: no, I only needed to track the X/Y coordinates of 1 object - square1. However, I have two objects on the stage that can be dragged and dropped: square1 and square2. When dragging square1, it shows the coordinates dynamically and hides square2. Everything works fine when dragging square1. But when I drag square2 it still gets hidden as if I'm dragging square1.

Comment: I know this is a separate question so maybe I should start another question thread lol...

Comment: @dzinermachine The most straightforward way is to define a separate set of **onStart** and **onStop** handlers for **square2**. But the most straightforward way is often the worst one in terms of scalability and the size of the script. I'll update my post in a minute.